# how to add extra css to a fabricjs text object?

Tags: css, fabricjs, border-image

when using fabricjs textbox, I'd like to add extra css to textbox so that the edit area is more beabutiful. 
The effect would be like this.
https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image

Anyone knows how to implement this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fabric doesn't support that and it would take a bunch of updating and straight up cavans drawing to make it happen.